# PFDavAdmin on SBS 2008/Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, exchange

I am trying to use PFDavAdmin to change folder permissions on an Exchange 2007 Server.
I am running the tool from Windows XP VM with .NET 1.1 installed and I am able to connect to the exchange server but it will not list the users or show any settings underneath.

The tool does successfully allow me to modify permissions in public folders but not for mailboxes

The following is the error I get
could not expand https://serverip/exchange. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made is when I was connecting to the server I put the IP instead of the FQDN of the server. Putting the FQDN fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the user running PFDavAdmin needs Full access permissions on the mailboxes they're trying to modify. You can easily manage Full access permissions from the EMC under the Recipient Configuration node.

Comment: Yes I am using the Domain Admin account in PFDavAdmin

Comment: I have updated the domain admin with full Access permissions but I still get the following error
When I connect I get the following error could not expand https://serverip/exchange. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1):

Domain admin account doesn't have full access permissions in Exchange 2007 by default...You need to explicatively give it full access permissions.

Comment: Ok I will try this and see how it goes. Is there a way to give the Domain admin account access to all the email addresses at once or do I have to manually edit each one

Comment: I tried doing this. When I connect I get the following error
could not expand https://serverip/exchange. Object reference not set to an instance of an object